# UnitTesting a controller that used QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Im trying with this TestMethod

```
[TestMethod]
        [Description("Checks if the SearchResults Controller is generating any data from the Report")]
        public async Task GetAllOldCustomersContainingTerm_FromSearchResultsControllerTest()
        {
            // Create mock configuration files for every class
            DalConfig config = new DalConfig()
            {
                ConnectionString = "Trusted_Connection=True;database=AdventureWorks2017;Server=localhost\\MSSQL2017",
            };

            // Create mock options, PrintService and logger
            var mockOptions = new Mock<IOptions<DalConfig>>();
            mockOptions.Setup(op => op.Value).Returns(config);
            var searchResultFunctions = new SearchResultFunctions();
            var logger = new Logger<SearchResultsController>(new LoggerFactory());

            var mockSearchResultServices = new Mock<SearchResultService>().As<ISearchResultService>();
            mockSearchResultServices.CallBase = true;

            // Terms to test. In MockDatabase, John exist on FirstName and 12345 on PostalCode
            var terms = new SearchTerms
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                PostalCode = "123456"
            };

            mockSearchResultServices.Setup(x => x.GetAllOldCustomersContainingTermAsync(config, terms))
                .ReturnsAsync(new WebApiMockDatabaseRecordsProvider().GetAllMockOldCustomersDtos());

            // Create mock controller
            var testController = new SearchResultsController(logger, mockSearchResultServices.Object, searchResultFunctions, mockOptions.Object);

            var result = await testController.GetAllOldCustomersContainingTermAsync() as OkObjectResult;

            // Check if data is being returned from the Controller
            Assert.IsTrue(result.Value != null);
```

To test the following controller.
Before i use QueryString i had a HttpGet with parameters and the test was succesful:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SearchResultsController : ControllerBase
    {
        readonly ILogger<SearchResultsController> _logger;
        ISearchResultService ResultService;
        ISearchResultFunctions ResultFunctions;
        DalConfig DalConfig;
        public SearchResultsController(ILogger<SearchResultsController> logger
            , ISearchResultService resultService, ISearchResultFunctions resultFunctions, IOptions<DalConfig> settings)
        {
            DalConfig = settings.Value;
            ResultService = resultService;
            ResultFunctions = resultFunctions;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns all customers with values that matches in any of the terms
        /// Searches all the customer fields except BusinessEntityId and BirthDate
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="terms">a list of string terms, seperated by space</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpGet("FindOldCustomers/{terms?}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllOldCustomersContainingTermAsync()
        {
            //if (terms == null)
                var terms = new SearchTerms()
                {
                    FirstName = Request.Query["FirstName"],
                    LastName = Request.Query["LastName"],
                    EmailAddress = Request.Query["EmailAddress"],
                    Gender = Request.Query["Gender"],
                    AddressLine1 = Request.Query["AddressLine1"],
                    AddressLine2 = Request.Query["AddressLine2"],
                    City = Request.Query["City"],
                    JobTitle = Request.Query["JobTitle"],
                    PhoneNumber = Request.Query["PhoneNumber"],
                    PostalCode = Request.Query["PostalCode"],
                };
            var config = new DalConfig()
            {
                ConnectionString = DalConfig.ConnectionString,
            };
            var task = await ResultService.GetAllOldCustomersContainingTermAsync(config, terms);
            if (task.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(ResultFunctions.ConvertToJSON(task));
        }
```

Im getting null reference exception, im not sure why.
Also im not sure if i somehow must pass to the controler the terms object. With parameters i was passing the terms from parameters.

Comment: I see this has been wrongly setup, `mockSearchResultServices.Setup(x => x.GetAllOldCustomersContainingTermAsync(config, terms))`. Moq use equility to match the setup, beter use `It.IsAny<DalConfig>()` and `It.IsAny<SearchTerms>()`

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks but i still get bull exception in the Request.Query[FirstName] of the controller IAction. I gurss request.query is null? How i can change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the null check (as suggested in your answer) is the right approach here.  While I wouldn't normally argue against that, there would be no way that the Request object could be null in a production environment.  In fact, by adding the null check, you are allowing the test to branch such that it is not really testing the functionality of the method as used in production.

The real solution would be to mock the Request so that you can provide the query string parameters that are expected by the Controller method.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22323841/4708097) for some advice on that.

Answer (score 0):

I Added in the controller a check to see if Request is null and now test passes